# Dropping items on death in roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

Did someone know how to do script that will drop every player item while player deads?
I'm learning roblox lua but i don't know how to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by items? Are you referring to the Tools that a player might have? Or the player's score and other values in the leaderboard? Have you tried scripting something yet or are you looking for a place to start?

Comment: I mean tools and i don't know how to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. put a remote event in replicated storage
2. name the remote event "DropItems
3. put a local script in starter player
4. type this into the local script:

```
local Char = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer.CharacterAdded:Wait()
Char.Humanoid.Died:Connect(Function()
   game.ReplicatedStorage.DropItems:FireServer(Char)
end)
```

5. put a script in the ServerScriptService
6. type this into the server script:

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.DropItems.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr,Char)
   local items = plr.BackPack:GetChildren()
   number = 1
   repeat 
      items[number].Parent = Game.Workspace
      number = number + 1
   until not items[number]
end)
```

7. enjoy! I spent a long time making this for you so I hope it works and tell me if it's broken as I would be happy to fix it for you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would be the best method but maybe try making it so when the player dies their items would be moved/cloned to the work space then teleported to the players location